# Focus particular editText in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

Basically I am using A listView inflated with imageview and EditText.

I want that when my last item of listView is being changed that is editext
another row should be added.

This part is working fine new row is added but i want that the focus should be on this row's editText but focus always comes on the first EditText.

In ListView descendability is set to "beforeDescendamnts".

Thank You !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi have you tried yourEdittext.requestFocus(true); on the editText you need focus

Comment: yeah I have tried that basically i want to focus at last one so in ListAdapter I do:-

if(position == (<list>.size() - 1))
 <edittext>.requestFocus();